# Unwanted drag on MacBook.Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

With my MacBook (MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) it occurs that, without me wanting it, an item is attached to my cursor and dragged. I am not able to replicate it when I want so when I called Apple they could not really help. Have some of you the same problem? Can you replicate it? Have you a solution?

Comment: Does this happen with the trackpad, mouse or both?  If you haven’t tested an external mouse, please do so and report back with the results.

Comment: Have you checked your Apple > System Preferences > Trackpad settings? And, if you're using a mouse, your Apple > System Preferences > Mouse settings?

Comment: I use the Trackpad. Which trackpad settings must I use?